# Cant create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare, eventlisteners

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a class which extends `Thread`. This class will read some bytes over `bluetooth`, and once its finished, or the last byte is read, it will call an `event listener` in order to update all the listening classes.

Like this in the bluetooth class:

```
fileCompleteInitiator.fileCompleted(fileName);
```

The implemented method creates an `AsyncTask` in order to process this file:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

   //other methods like onCreate..

    @Override
    public void fileComplete(String fileName) {

     if(fileName.endsWith(".zip")) {    
        CaseGenerator generator = new CaseGenerator(Home.this, fileName, lastCases, nist); 
        generator.execute("");
      }
    }
}
```

Inside this asynctask, I want to show a `progressdialog`, but I get the not-so-original exception:

```
Cant create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare
```

The code for it is the usual thing, create the `progressdialog` in `onPreExecute()` and dismiss it in the `onPostExecute()`. Some code

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setTitle("Please Wait..");
        pd.setMessage("Generating file");
        pd.show();
    }
     .....................

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();
     }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are you calling fileComplete from a Thread != UIThread ?

Comment: Yeah, I am calling fileComplete from a Thread. What is the easiest way of showing progressdialog from here?

Comment: you should create and execute your asynctask from the UI Thread

Answer (score 1):

You need to be creating and executing your `AsyncTask` from the main application thread. That's a requirement of `AsyncTask` anyway, last I checked, and it will address your `onPreExecute()` problems.

Comment: The method which executes the `AsyncTask`, is in an `Activity`. This method, fileComplete, will be called from the `Thread` saying that the file is complete.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen: Then `fileComplete()` needs to arrange to create and execute your `AsyncTask` from the main application thread, such as via `runOnUiThread()`.